# Customizing view model data-annotation error : An attribute argument must be a constant expression,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC3 project, I have a view model like this where i have the Error message hard coded for the Properties.

```
public class UserProfileVM
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name should be 10 chars")]
  public string Name { set;get;}

 //other properties
}
```

I want to dynamically load the value of `ErrorMessage` attribute based on the user's preference settings (language user opted for). So i have function which returns the language label like this

```
public string GetLabel(string labelCode)
{
  string labelText="Get from somewhere using labelCode";
  //Get User's language preference from Session and return the labelText here
  return labelText;
}
```

I tried to use it like this in my view model

```
[Required]
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = GetLabel("MinCharErr"))]
public string Name { set;get;}
```

***But i am not able to compile my code. I am getting an error like
An attribute argument must be a constant expression,typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type***

Can someone tell me how to fix that. I need to use the `GetLabel` method to get the relevant text.

Comment: Did you find the below useful ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own `StringLength` class to implement this:

```
public class CustomStringLength : StringLengthAttribute {
    public CustomStringLength() {
        //Set your error message right here
        base.ErrorMessage = userOptions.GetErrorByLabel(labelCode);
    }
}
```

Obviously this will need to wire up to your back-end data, but, this is the general idea of how you can dynamically set the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> But i am not able to compile my code. I am getting an error like An
>   attribute argument must be a constant expression,typeof expression or
>   array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Because you cannot Customize the Properties like `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` to fetch some Dynamic results.

You can only Customize the `Length` Property in `StringLengthAttribute` class by passing the Parameterized Constructor in your Customized class. That means you can only `Override` the `Length` of `String`

Like you said you want to pass some key to get the corresponding `Error Message`, that is not possible.

You can also write the below mentioned Message in you Resource file

```
"Maximum allowed length is {0}"
```

and at run time you can Format the String by Replacing it with Parametrized Constructor value(which is Max String Length) in your Custom Class

> Get User's language preference from Session and return the labelText
>   here

You have set the language in you Global.asax file. So, your resource file will be picked according to the `UserLanguage`. So, just specify the Key name and corresponding value will be fetched from `Resource file` according to the selected language

**How can I set the language?**

```
public sealed class LanguageManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default CultureInfo
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly CultureInfo DefaultCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    /// <summary>
    /// Available CultureInfo that according resources can be found
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly CultureInfo[] AvailableCultures;

    static LanguageManager()
    {
        List<string> availableResources = new List<string>();
        string resourcespath = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_GlobalResources");
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(resourcespath);
        foreach (FileInfo fi in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*.resx", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            //Take the cultureName from resx filename, will be smt like en-US
            string cultureName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name); //get rid of .resx
            if (cultureName.LastIndexOf(".") == cultureName.Length - 1)
                continue; //doesnt accept format FileName..resx
            cultureName = cultureName.Substring(cultureName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            availableResources.Add(cultureName);
        }

        List<CultureInfo> result = new List<CultureInfo>();
        foreach (CultureInfo culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            //If language file can be found
            if (availableResources.Contains(culture.ToString()))
            {
                result.Add(culture);
            }
        }

        AvailableCultures = result.ToArray();

        CurrentCulture = DefaultCulture;
        if (!result.Contains(DefaultCulture) && result.Count > 0)
        {
            CurrentCulture = result[0];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current selected culture
    /// </summary>
    public static CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get { return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; }
        set
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
        }
    }
}
```